# Python set not changing the length of new list?

Tags: python

Using python I converted a list to set and back to list to remove the duplicates. But the length of the new list is unmodified. How do we get the length of the new list?

Python code:

```
values = [2,3,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6]
print(len(values))
print(list(set(values)))
print(len(values))
```

output:

```
10
[2, 3, 5, 6]
10
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing a step in your example.  What you are attempting works for me:

```
>>> values = [ 2, 3, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 ]
>>> len(values)
10
>>> set(values)
set([2, 3, 5, 6])
>>> list(set(values))
[2, 3, 5, 6]
>>> len(list(set(values)))
4
```

In your example, you are printing `len(values)` twice without ever changing the contents of `values`, so naturally it's going to print the same thing again.